# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'apply'

Tags: sql-server, azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Am trying to use cross apply in azure data bricks notebook it throws the error that incorrect syntax near apply while the same query is working fine in SQL server.Is azure data bricks notebook is not supporting  apply operators?

```
enter ## Connection parameters ##
sqlserver = 'servername'
port = '1433'
database = 'dbname'
user = 'username'
pswd = "pwd"
query = "(select * from repair_detail a\
cross apply (select  top 1 * from order c where a.RO_NO=c.RO_NO) b\
     ) AS CustSales"


## Load Data Frame ##
df1 = spark.read \
.option('user', user) \
.option('password', pswd) \
.jdbc('jdbc:sqlserver://' + sqlserver + ':' + port + ';database=' +database, 
 query)

# Show the resulting DataFrame
df1.show()
```

Comment: Are you sure it works? The query as written is missing the SELECT at the start. Maybe spark puts that - I dunno.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes its working when i use any other operators like join